# Intellij-IDEA Gradle dsl-Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea

how to have gradle options menu on intellij idea generator?
While I saw Intellij Idea on YouTube, on average there is a gradle menu option in the generator section

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the **Gradle** and **Kotlin** bundled plugins enabled.